# Search in 2 tables for 1 result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question for my search bar:
In Account Management, I have list of accounts
And this is the Account table:

*AccountID (Example: 1)
*AccountName (Example: Test)
(...)

Now, When I type Test, or 1, I find my result.

My problem is how to search by typing one of character name, this is the characters table:

*CharacterName (Example: Charac)
*AccountID (1 [the same accountID])

I've tried INNER JOIN but it's not working, and i think it isn't the correct method, this is my SQL code

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM account INNER JOIN characterrecord ON characterrecord.AccountId = account.AccountId WHERE account.AccountId LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR account.Name LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR characterrecord.Name LIKE '%" . $name ."%' GROUP BY account.accountid LIMIT ".$_GET['page'].",".$page_accountnumber;
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
        while ($acc = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
    ....
```

What I want:
If I type Charac or char ... I must see 1/Test (Character account infos).

Sorry for my bad english, I'm french, and thank you so much!

Comment: Elaborate on "not working". Incorrect result, no result, error?

Comment: No error, I have the names of characters and not of accounts..

Comment: So, you need account name by character search?

Comment: You should have both, your results (due to SELECT *) should include all fields from both tables; however, since they use the same field name, there may be some ambiguity when dealing with results. Try replacing `*` with the fields you want to see `SELECT account.Name` for example.

Comment: I need account name by character search/account search, my problem now is just character search

Comment: Ok I will try it Uueerdo thank's

Comment: This time I have empty result:with this SELECT account.accountid, account.name, account.isactive, account.rolegroupname..

Comment: Strange, you left the rest of the query the same?

Comment: AHHH NOO SORRY, I've typed account,accountid, account.name.. and not account,AccountId, account.Name without capitals. It's WORK, thank you very much Uueerdo, you can add your answer for best answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tables share certain field names, it may be necessary to specify or alias the fields in the `SELECT` clause to ensure whatever framework you are handling them with is capable of distinguishing them.